# Passing PHP variable in JS using div id

Tags: php, javascript

I have some pages. In these pages i want to show the error message.
Now i am showing these message through JavaScript.But the code is repeated so many times that's why i have decided to define this message as a constant in config file.

I accessed this constant `STORE_OFFLINE_MSG` in a div. And then I am using the html of this div , this function return the text of the div as defined in config file and passes it in the variable of JS
this is the code in my config file config.php:

```
  define('STORE_OFFLINE_MSG','hello');
```

This is the sort of code of php file abc.php

```
<div class="storeOfflineMsg"><?php  echo STORE_OFFLINE_MSG;?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var msg = $(".storeOfflineMsg").html();
  $.prompt('<h3 Store unavailable</h3>'+msg);
</script>
```

but if i used this variable in other file only by using the div class then .html() returns NULL.

My second file xyz.php is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var msg = $(".storeOfflineMsg").html();
  $.prompt('Store unavailable</h3>'+msg);
</script>
```

Please suggest me what to do. and how can i get a php constant in the Java Script through div class.

Comment: Does your second one include the div as well?

You can also directly echo the string out into the javascript code as follows: $.prompt('<h3 Store unavailable</h3><?php  echo STORE_OFFLINE_MSG;?>');

Answer (score 4):

You can store the variable directly in javascript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var msg = "<?php  echo STORE_OFFLINE_MSG;?>";
```

Comment: it's fine if it's just a constant, but don't put any user data in JS - it's a perfect place for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from PHP to Javascript try this:

echo the data out in the  of your page within a script section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
   echo 'var offlineMsg = ' . STORE_OFFLINE_MSG . ';';
   echo 'var onlineMsg = ' . STORE_OnLINE_MSG . ';';
?>
</script>
```

These Javascript variables will then be availabe globally to all other javascript code on the page. Much better than placing it in a hidden div.